# 100% width in css without the doesn't depend on browser size

Tags: css

I want to add 100% width to my website. The problem is that If I do so, the design and the size of the contents changes with the change of the browser size. I want to make the contents inside the webpage constants although I give the size of the boxes in %

Comment: "I want absolute relative sizing that fills the width but does not change with the browser size" ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper `div` with a fixed width, and then  any element's width within it will be relative to that width.

eg

```
#wrapper {
width: 800px;
}
div {
width 80%; /*div will be 80% of 800px ie 640px*/
}
```

Comment: why you give width to a body. Never give width to a body it's not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix min-width with % width of body, this will resize but will not let elements to get crushed if browser is thinned.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body,html{ margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; min-width:800px;}
    #container{
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    #header, #content, #footer{
      min-width:700px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
div{
    min-height:40px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
?
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
        container
       <div id="header">header</div>
       <div id="content">content</div>
       <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you can put contents in fixed width divs and put those inside of variable width div(%) and position them with `margin` or `padding`

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify maximum-width/height for the components which you feel as should not be re-sized.